Detect AR anchor on human body in iOS
I am working on an iOS app for a client that overlays a an image using AR on a point on your body. This anchoring is currently done by the user drawing a sign on the desired spot. This is not a good user experience and I would like to find a way so the user does not need to draw anything on his body.
Currently, ARKit performs anchoring using surface detection or with a physical anchor like an image or an object. The problem, for example, with someone’s arm is that it’s not a flat surface. But theoretically, an iPhone Pro has a LiDAR sensor that could detect that arm and where it is in space. So, it could detect any point on it as well.
Or I could train an ML model to detect that sign.
Do you know how this problem could be approached?
Thank you.

It seems that in your case there is nothing better than using ARBodyAnchor (or, when you prefer RealityKit anchoring, AnchorEntity(.body)). If you provided your session with ARBodyTrackingConfig, you will end up with a human body skeletal system consisting of 92 joints, where the root joint is located in the pelvic area of the tracked skeleton. You can use each joint to place 3d models.

In order to use ARBodyAnchor isn't it necessary for the entire body of the person to be visible? This is not feasible in our case. We want the user to point the camera to a body part like an arm or a leg and show an image over that. Also, for the entire body to be visible, someone else needs to hold the iPhone.

If you want just a single part of the body to be detected (not the whole body), then you should train .mlmodel and use the CoreML / Vision frameworks (you are right). The most difficult part of your code will be a translation of the Vision's 2D coordinates into ARKit's 3D coordinates.

Can the LIDAR sensor help with this translation?

In some sense, yes, if you can provide a two-way communication between Vision-world and ARKit-world.
